# Acumatica error :Error: The system failed to commit the MapFrom row

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Please help me to importing Inter-Branch Account Mapping using import scenarios.
i get the following error:

> "Error: The system failed to commit the MapFrom row."

Please explain what is the error because original branch related to multiple  destination branches. When i keying manually working nut using import scenario not working. Please advise. Thanks You

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck column 'Commit' for all columns.
Only check this column for field 'Original branch' and Action Save.

This does the work for me!

Comment: Thanks, this should've been marked as answered (saved me time on troubleshooting).